# For any ideal, why must a ring homomorphism be surjective for the ideal to be mapped to an ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism, epimorphisms

**Problem:**

Let $f$: $R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism

Show that if $f$ is surjective, then for any ideal $I \subset R$, the set $f(I)$ is an ideal of $S$.

**My Solution:**

Let $x,y\in I\subset R\implies f(x),f(y)\in f(I)\subset S$

1. $0\in I\implies f(0)=0\in f(I)$
2. $x+y\in I\implies f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\in f(I)$
3. $-x\in I\implies f(-x)=-f(x)\in f(I)$
4. $r\in R, x\in I, r\cdot x\in I\implies f(r\cdot x)=f(r)\cdot f(x)\in f(I),f(r)\in S, f(x)\in f(I)$
5. $x\in I, r\in R, x\cdot r\in I\implies f(x\cdot r)=f(x)\cdot f(r)\in f(I),f(x)\in I, f(r)\in f(S)$

Thus $f(I)$ is an ideal of $S$

**My Question:**

If my solution is correct, why does f need to be surjective?

Comment: Consider the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$.  Certainly the image is not an ideal.

Comment: Your problem is step (4). You don’t know $s f(r)$ is in $f(I)$ for any $r\in I,$ $s\in S,$ only for $s\in f(R).$

Comment: What do steps 3, 4, and 5 have to do with being an ideal?

Comment: In step (5) you mention $f(S).$ That’s meaningless for a function $f:R\to S.$ Did you mean $f(I)?$

Comment: The problem with step (4) is also a problem with step (5), of course. I was sort of assuming we were talking commutative rights rather than general rings with “ideal” meaning left-right ideals.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In step (5) I meant S instead of f(S)

Comment: @MarkSaving In my course notes an Ideal is defined as follows: A subest $I\subset R$ is an ideal of $R$ if (1) $I$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$ and (2) $a\in I, r\in R\implies ra\in I, ar\in I$. My steps 1 to 3 were to show (1) and my steps 4 and 5 were to show (2).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews perhaps the way I wrote it was incorrect. What I am trying to say in step 4 (and similarly in step 5) is that since $r\cdot x\in I$ this implies that $f(r\cdot x)\in f(I)$ and since $f(r)\cdot f(x)=f(r\cdot x)$ this implies that $[f(r)\cdot f(x)]\in f(I)$.

Comment: @Luke I understood that. But for $f(I)$ to be an ideal of $S,$ you need for any $s\in S$ and $f(r)\in f(I)$ you need $sf(r)\in f(I).$ If $f$ is not onto, you have only proven for $s\in f(R),$ not for all $s\in S.$

Comment: @Luke I see now that your step 3 is relevant (though it the fact that $-x \in I$ follows from the fact that $-1 \cdot x \in I$). But steps 4 and 5 do not have anything to do with proving (2).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah yes, that makes perfect sense. You're previous comment also made perfect sense but it was 1am for me so my brain wasn't working properly. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @MarkSaving Is it not sufficient to just say $-x\in I$ (since $I$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$ which means that $\forall x\in I, \exists -x\in I$) or do I need to write what you wrote?

Comment: @MarkSaving why do steps 4 and 5 have nothing to do with proving (2)? I have shown that $f(x)\in f(I), s\in S\implies f(x)\cdot s\in f(I), \forall f(x)\in f(I), s\in S$ and similarly for $s\cdot f(x)$, where as Thomas has explained, I can use $f(r)$ and $s$ interchangeably $\forall s\in S$ because $f$ is surjective. This proves (2) right?